# Python lxml finding element by id-tag

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I am working on a python program for keeping an inventory of a storage room. In a XML-document the amount of toners will be kept and I want my python program to be able to add, remove and display the amount of toners for different printers and different colors.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<printer>
    <t id="095205615111"> <!-- 7545 Magenta -->
        <toner>7545 Magenta Toner</toner>
        <amount>3</amount>
    </t>
    <t id="095205615104"> <!-- 7545 Yellow -->
        <toner>7545 Yellow Toner</toner>
        <amount>7</amount>
    </t>
</printer>
```

The id is the number from the barcode that we use for inventory.

So far I have these steps that I would like my program to use:

1. Check if the id exist (the id-value is a variable in my python program piped from the content in a txt-file)
2. Change the value of amount in the xml-document to +1 or -1

Whatever I try it never works fully. Do you have any suggestions of what I could use?

Comment: post your code, whatever you tried

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Check if the id exist

You can solve this by constructing an XPath expression checking the `@id` attribute value.

> Change the value of amount in the xml-document to +1 or -1

Once you locate the `t` node by a specific `id`, you can use `find()` to locate the inner `amount` node. Then, you can get the `.text`, convert it into an integer, change it, convert back to string and set the `.text` property.

The working example:

```py
from lxml import etree

data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<printer>
    <t id="095205615111"> <!-- 7545 Magenta -->
        <toner>7545 Magenta Toner</toner>
        <amount>3</amount>
    </t>
    <t id="095205615104"> <!-- 7545 Yellow -->
        <toner>7545 Yellow Toner</toner>
        <amount>7</amount>
    </t>
</printer>"""


root = etree.fromstring(data)

toner_id = "095205615111"

# find a toner
results = root.xpath("//t[@id = '%s']" % toner_id)
if not results:
    raise Exception("Toner does not exist")

toner = results[0]

# change the amount
amount = toner.find("amount")
amount.text = str(int(amount.text) + 1)

print(etree.tostring(root))
```

Comment: @Diego no problem. Try posting the things you tried next time - this would bring more attention and help understand the problems you have better. Also, consider accepting an answer to resolve the topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can also approach it with [`lxml.objectify`](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) which would make handling the data types easier:

```py
from lxml import objectify, etree

data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<printer>
    <t id="095205615111"> <!-- 7545 Magenta -->
        <toner>7545 Magenta Toner</toner>
        <amount>3</amount>
    </t>
    <t id="095205615104"> <!-- 7545 Yellow -->
        <toner>7545 Yellow Toner</toner>
        <amount>7</amount>
    </t>
</printer>"""


root = objectify.fromstring(data)

toner_id = "095205615111"

# find a toner
results = root.xpath("//t[@id = '%s']" % toner_id)
if not results:
    raise Exception("Toner does not exist")

toner = results[0]

# change the amount
toner.amount += 1

# dump the tree object back to XML string
objectify.deannotate(root)
etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)
print(etree.tostring(root))
```

Note, how the amount change is implemented:

```py
toner.amount += 1
```