# How to scale a path element in an SVG file with Python

Tags: python, svg, scale

My Inkscape-made SVG contains a path with a unique ID that I want to scale around its center. Here's what it looks like:

[image: source svg]

I know the id of the element, so I used `svgutils` to scale it:

```
import svgutils.transform as sg
fig = sg.fromfile('smile.svg')
mouth = fig.find_id('path1069')
factor = 1.25
mouth.scale(factor)
fig.save('smile-fail.svg')
```

The result scales from the top-left corner of the entire SVG canvas and it's not great:

[image: failed scaling]

Instead it should look like this when I scale it around the center by holding SHIFT and CTRL while scaling in Inkscape:

[image: intended scaling Inkscape sample]

The SVG in question:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="200"
   height="200"
   viewBox="0 0 200 200"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   inkscape:version="1.2.2 (732a01da63, 2022-12-09)"
   sodipodi:docname="smile.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#eeeeee"
     borderopacity="1"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:deskcolor="#ffffff"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="2"
     inkscape:cx="125.5"
     inkscape:cy="87"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <pattern
       inkscape:collect="always"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       width="2"
       height="2"
       patternTransform="translate(0,0) scale(10,10)"
       id="Checkerboard"
       inkscape:stockid="Checkerboard"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <rect
         style="fill:black;stroke:none"
         x="0"
         y="0"
         width="1"
         height="1"
         id="rect1912" />
      <rect
         style="fill:black;stroke:none"
         x="1"
         y="1"
         width="1"
         height="1"
         id="rect1914" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       style="fill:#aca694;fill-opacity:1;"
       id="rect403"
       width="200"
       height="100"
       x="-6.357829e-07"
       y="99.999367" />
    <circle
       style="fill:#d1c7b4;fill-opacity:1;"
       id="path241"
       cx="97.803673"
       cy="94.830917"
       r="65.697899" />
    <circle
       style="fill:url(#Checkerboard);fill-opacity:1;opacity:0.1"
       id="circle2820"
       cx="97.803673"
       cy="94.830917"
       r="65.697899" />
    <circle
       style="fill:#fff7e7;fill-opacity:1"
       id="path1011"
       cx="77.145447"
       cy="70.418861"
       r="14.504185" />
    <circle
       style="fill:#fff7e7;fill-opacity:1"
       id="circle1013"
       cx="119.08147"
       cy="68.001495"
       r="16.921549" />
    <path
       style="fill:#fff7e7;fill-opacity:1"
       d="m 80,100 40,5 c 0,0 3.69099,14.51519 -20,15 -23.690996,0.4848 -20,-20 -20,-20 z"
       id="path1069"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="cczc" />
    <circle
       style="fill:#292827;fill-opacity:1"
       id="circle1512"
       cx="79.523659"
       cy="70.418861"
       r="7.3695707" />
    <circle
       style="fill:#292827;fill-opacity:1"
       id="circle1514"
       cx="118.02084"
       cy="67.892021"
       r="9.8964138" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

[svgpathtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297053) to the rescue, either combined with `svgutils`' `tostr()` to hopefully extract the `d` attribute or in combination with [getting an element by ID in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41187226) whilst [avoiding confusing namespace mess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56936158/188159):

```
import svgutils.transform as sg
from svgpathtools import parse_path

fig = sg.fromfile('smile.svg')
mouth = fig.find_id('path1069')

# scaling
factor = 1.25
mouth.scale(factor)

# dirty-ish capture of path data
path = mouth.tostr().decode().lower().split(' d="')[1].split('" ')[0]

# cleaner capture of path data https://stackoverflow.com/a/41187226
import lxml.etree as ET
svg = ET.parse('smile.svg')
# using * because can't figure out namespaces https://stackoverflow.com/a/56936158/188159
path = svg.xpath('//*[@id = "path1069"]')[0].attrib['d']

# coordinates of the path's bounding box https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297053
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = parse_path(path).bbox()

# width/height calc
w = xmax - xmin
h = ymax - ymin

# center point calc
cx = xmin + w/2
cy = ymin + h/2

# diff between original/new center points
x = cx - cx * factor
y = cy - cy * factor

#correctional movement
mouth.moveto(x,y)

fig.save('smile-scale_and_move.svg')
```

[image: correctly center-scaled svg]